# How to cancel Noise in voice call swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, agora.io

I am doing a calling app using agora in swift. I have implemented voice calls, but I need to cancel the external noise during calls. Can I achieve that? Is that possible? If it is how can I do that?

Comment: If I am not wrong, noise cancellation will be provided by your device (headphone) & not with agora. I use agora and voice goes fine...

Answer (score 0):

Noice cancellation will be hardware dependent, but as you are using agora you can check the below link to set the appropriate audio profile and test the audio quality.

Refer this link: https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/audio_profile_apple?platform=iOS

Comment: Welcome @JoiceGeorge, please post here if you found any better solution on this.